# Rocky Linux on Oracle VirtualBox consistently freezes after a short period of inactivity

Tags: freeze, kernel-panic

Using journatctl I can see "unchecked MSR access error"s:

```
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel: unchecked MSR access error: WRMSR to 0x2ff0 (tried to write 0x0000000020000000) at rIP: 0xffffffffa4676294 (native_write_msr+0x4/0x>
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel: Call Trace:
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  ? ex_handler_wrmsr_unsafe.cold.2+0x2e/0x3d
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  ? fixup_exception+0x33/0x46
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  ? gp_try_fixup_and_notify+0x1b/0xa0
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  ? do_general_protection+0xba/0x280
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  ? update_load_avg+0x7e/0x710
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  ? general_protection+0x1e/0x30
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  ? native_write_msr+0x4/0x20
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  adl_uncore_msr_init_box+0x27/0x30 [intel_uncore]
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  uncore_box_ref.part.24+0x9c/0xc0 [intel_uncore]
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  ? uncore_pci_pmu_unregister+0x90/0x90 [intel_uncore]
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  uncore_event_cpu_online+0x52/0x1b0 [intel_uncore]
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  ? uncore_pci_pmu_unregister+0x90/0x90 [intel_uncore]
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  ? sort_range+0x20/0x20
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  cpuhp_invoke_callback+0x8e/0x510
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  ? sort_range+0x20/0x20
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  cpuhp_thread_fun+0xb4/0x110
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  smpboot_thread_fn+0xb5/0x150
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  kthread+0x134/0x150
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  ? set_kthread_struct+0x50/0x50
Feb 13 18:30:53 RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org kernel:  ret_from_fork+0x1f/0x40
```

System info:

```
$ uname -a
Linux RockyLinux.myguest.virtualbox.org 4.18.0-513.11.1.el8_9.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jan 10 22:58:54 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What might be the cause of this?

**Update**

I have upgraded to kernel 6.7.4 but I'm still having kernel panics

[image: Rocky Linux kernel panic]

(I'm posting a screenshot because copy and paste between guest and host no longer works.)

The

Comment: Looks like this [reported kernel issue](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203637). Try to upgrade the kernel.

Comment: Upgrading does not seem to solve the problem. (See update to OP.)

Comment: I have Removed Rocky Linux and installed Alma Linux instead. Alma Linux is not as rocky but its not as response as Ubuntu either.